# Trying Highstock to convert very old graph application but no display

Tags: highcharts

I am in the process of moving from a built in graph library to [**HighStock**](http://www.highcharts.com).

I have to comply to crasy implementations. So at the end I got this configuration :

```
$(function() {
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'div_#divid#'
        },
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 0,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 7,
                text: '7j'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 15,
                text: '15j'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 30,
                text: '30j'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'Tous'
            }]
        },
        series : [{
            type : 'column',
            name : 'valeur',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

**[`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/SqZY2/)** is the fiddled version.

I don't get whats wrong with my data. (but I think I did correctly the conversion for the dates.)

```
[[1362355200000,672],[1362441600000,9764],[1362528000000,9839],[1362614400000,9906],  [1362700800000,9973],[1362787200000,9906],[1362873600000,10592],[1362960000000,11236],  [1363046400000,13233],[1363132800000,0],[1363219200000,0],[1363305600000,0],[1363392000000,0],[1363478400000,0],[1363564800000,0],[1363651200000,0],[1363737600000,0],[1363824000000,0],[1363910400000,0],[1363996800000,0],[1364083200000,0],[1364169600000,0],[1364256000000,0],[1364342400000,0],[1364428800000,0],[1364515200000,0],[1364601600000,0],[1364688000000,0],[1364770800000,0],[1364857200000,0],[1364943600000,0],[1365030000000,0],[1365116400000,0],[1365202800000,0],[1365289200000,0],[1365375600000,0],[1365462000000,0],[1365548400000,0],[1365634800000,0],[1365721200000,0],[1365807600000,0],[1365894000000,0],[1365980400000,0],[1366066800000,0],[1366153200000,0],[1366239600000,0],[1366326000000,0],[1366412400000,0],[1366498800000,0],[1366585200000,0],[1366671600000,0],[1366758000000,0],[1366844400000,0],[1366930800000,0],[1367017200000,0],[1367103600000,0],[1367190000000,0],[1367276400000,0],[1367362800000,0],[1367449200000,5490]]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks Gopinagh for the edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, the problem is that you can't see the chart? That's cause your data contains '

Check the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SqZY2/1/
You have this:

```
data = '[[1362355200000,672],[1362441600000,9764],[1367103600000,0],[1367190000000,0],[1367276400000,0],[1367362800000,0],[1367449200000,5490]]';
```

Must be this:

```
data = [[1362355200000,672],[1362441600000,9764],[1362528000000,9839],[1362614400000,9906],[1367103600000,0],[1367190000000,0],[1367276400000,0],[1367362800000,0],[1367449200000,5490]];
```

Comment: Lucky I made this mistake in fiddle, as I just had to evaluate the string in my js code !! THANKS Lorenzo !!